# ActiveMQ - what is the async message lifespan?

Tags: activemq-classic

When producing a message to an ActiveMQ queue with userAsyncSend=true and deliveryMode=persistent, what's happening with that message?

1. Is the message being saved to the RAM prior to persistence to disk?
2. If the persistence fails, is it possible that consumers will consume the message despite the failure?

Couldn't find any information about this on ActiveMQ official documentation.